# In WooCommerce, Is it possible to display specific country only if cart total is over 100?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have tried to do it using a filter hook called "woocommerce_countries". I tried getting the cart total in this hook but it's not working. Is anyone have any idea on this OR suggest any hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this code. WooCommerce `3.6.2`, they have removed the ability to check the cart data. But cart session is accessible right now so we use this function `WC()->session->cart`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'products_disable_country', 10, 1 );
function products_disable_country( $countries ) {
    $cartdata = WC()->session->cart;
    if (is_array($cartdata) && !empty($cartdata)) {
        foreach ($cartdata as $itemdata) {
            $sum += $itemdata['line_total'];
        }
        if ($sum >= 100) {
            unset($countries["CA"]);
        }
    }
    return $countries;
}
```

Comment: Thank @Team Dolphins, I made minor changes and it almost works. Only facing issue when updating cart quantity. Like, it's only reflected when the page refresh.

Comment: on the cart page change Change address? I will check my local demo with storefront theme it's work on update cart

Comment: While changing the quantity on the cart page.

Comment: on cart page It's Work with storefront theme so may be it's conflict with your theme